# Minimum BlackBerry Messenger version to access BBM SDK 1.0

Tags: blackberry

Do I need BlackBerry Messenger 6.0 to access BBM SDK 1.0?

Can I use this BBM SDK with BlackBerry Messenger 5.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. You need BBM 6.0.  You can get the beta from http://www.blackberry.com/beta

Answer (score 0):

BlackBerry Messenger non-beta is now available on RIM AppWorld.